# How can I convert a nested function code into readable boolean algebra?

Tags: python, parsing, tree, boolean-algebra

For this program I'm writing, I am writing a program that needs to simplify and read/output boolean expressions. To do this, I need to be able to convert between codes like:

`AND(OR(a,b), NOT(OR(c,a)))`

into

`(A+B).'(C+A)`

and vice versa, with all the operators working as `AND(a,b)`, `OR(a,b)` and `NOT(a)`, where a and b are variables/parameters (they represent actual functions in my program).

I have no idea how to approach this, so if there is anything you can offer to guide me, I would be very thankful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So putting aside the problem of evaluating a given Boolean expression, you ultimately have a string of code that's in one particular format, and you want to re-format it to a string of a different type.  One way to change from the first format to the second is to make actual functions in Python called "AND", "OR", and "NOT" (three words which have no other special meanings in Python, when they are written in all-caps like that). Then define each function to print output of the second logic format.  So running `AND("x","y")` for example returns the three-character string "`x.y`":

```
def AND(a,b):
    return "(%s.%s)" % (a, b)

def OR(a,b):
    return "(%s+%s)" % (a, b)

def NOT(a):
    return "'(%s)" % a

a, b, c = "a", "b", "c"
myfirstbool = "AND(OR(a,b), NOT(OR(c,a)))"
mynewbool = eval(myfirstbool)  # Take the string, and treat it as Python code
print(mynewbool)  # output:  ((a+b).'((c+a)))
```

This may give you some redundant parentheses, but the final expression is still valid.

Going the other way is a little trickier, because you have to count the nested parentheses to get things correct.  You may want to look up algorithms on how nested parentheses can be parsed in Python, how to find things like "`*+*`" in regular expressions, or the [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/logic.html) module.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very clever :) Unfortunately I cannot use any external modules for this program, so I will have to devise my own algorithm to make it work backwards

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help.  Some suggestions I'd have are: first replace the string "NOT" with the apostrophe, since that's the easiest; remove any whitespaces, since you don't need them; and finally have a recursive function that looks for the inner-most parentheses, and replace things from the inside out.  You may want to try replacing "a+b" with "OR[a,b]" at first, using brackets instead of parentheses so that your algorithm ignores "[a,b]" in recursive searches.  Then when you're finally done, replace all of the brackets with parentheses.

Comment: I'm trying to write the code for this now, but wouldn't it be easier to just scan the equation left to right and everytime it encounters an operation, like '+.'⊕', it replaces it with the corresponding code? Like 'a.(c+b)' becomes AND(a, c+b) then AND(a,OR(c,b)), instead of using recursion?

Comment: Whether your function processes the entire string, or just recursively replaces the string as it looks for the first occurrence of an operator (so that you can keep feeding it until it doesn't find any, then you're done), you still just have to be careful with how your code recognizes the boundaries. If you have something like "( b + ((c.d)+e) ).a", your code needs to know that the "OR" it makes with "b" should be made with "(c.d)+e", not "(c.d)", or "c" or "((c.d)+e)).a".